# What library versions does mavenCentral() import?

Tags: java, gradle, repository, version, maven-central

I am working on a project with Gradle and I have the following in the build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

and I was wondering what version of Apache Commons Codec for example is this importing.  (more info about mavenCentral() [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html) )

The question is not how I find out the version (mine is 1.11) but what is the logic behind the default choosing of a specific version.

Comment: `mavenCentral()` doesn't import any libraries. It tells Gradle how to locate dependencies that you declare when [declaring dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html)

Comment: then my problem changes: where does the Apache Commons Codec comes from if I only have in the implementation area these : group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0' ;   group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.7' ;  group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.13'  ?

Comment: The easiest way to find out why Apache Commons Codec is included is to run the Gradle "dependencies" task. This prints out a tree structure of your direct dependencies and of the things they depend on in turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a gradle file like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0' 
    implementation group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.7'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.13'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

If you want to know which dependencies in total are included and why then you can execute `gradle dependencies` and it will show you among others) this graph:

```
compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0
+--- commons-validator:commons-validator:1.7
|    +--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4
|    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    |    \--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2
|    +--- commons-digester:commons-digester:2.1
|    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    \--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2
\--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13
     +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.13
     +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
     \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11
```

This graph shows that `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13` (which you explicitly mention in your dependencies) depends upon `commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11` and therefore `commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11` is included in your project as well.